# Wordcloud2 it's not showing the words on top of custom images when using figpath

Tags: r, word-cloud, wordcloud2

Wordcloud2 it's not showing the words on top of custom images when using figpath.
Dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TCprm9I0fatD868SolA0EO9jemIDOa9S/view?usp=share_link

My code:

```
library(wordcloud2)
library(tidyverse)

data =  read_csv("pokemon.csv")
#View(data)

pokemons = data %>% 
  filter(Generation==1) %>% 
  select(Name, Liked)

wordcloud2(data=pokemons, size = 0.2, color=data$Colors, figPath = "./pikachu_white.png")
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: Where is the column `Liked`?

Comment: I forgot I added that, let me edit 

Comment: @Quinten there you have it

Comment: Could you please share the image?